# CSS Positioning: Set to images below and 1 image on top of the first image (jsfiddle included)

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-position

**What I am trying to do:**

[image]

**What I´ve done**

**jsfiddle:**  http://jsfiddle.net/eyyo/gUuVn/1/

```
<div style="left: 0; top: 0;">
    <img src="images/tit_fondo1.jpg" style="position: relative ; z-index: 1;"/>
    <img src="images/tit_fondo2.jpg" style="position: absolute ; z-index: 1;"/>
    <img src="images/tit_titulo.png" style="position: relative ; z-index: 2;"/>


    <div style="text-align:center; margin-left: auto ;margin-right: auto ;width:80%;">
        <p style="color:#755C48; font:italic 10px arial;position: relative ; z-index:
         2;">“Paragraph with a shor text of two or three lines”</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem with this is that the img C cant be on top of img A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/gUuVn/3/

```
 <div style="left: 0; top: 0;position: relative;">
        <img src="http://s22.postimg.org/o27ibahxd/tit_fondo1.jpg" style="position: relative ; z-index: 1;"/>
     <br/>  <img src="http://s16.postimg.org/8ysqmfif9/tit_fondo2.jpg" style="position: relative ; z-index: 1;"/>
        <img src="http://s10.postimg.org/xt62u60dh/intro_bandera1.png" style="position: relative ; z-index: 2;position: absolute;left:0;top:0;"/>


        <div style="position: absolute;bottom: -2px;left: 0;margin-left: auto ;margin-right: auto ;width:80%;">
            <p style="color:#755C48; font:italic 10px arial;position: relative ; z-index:
             2;">“Paragraph with a shor text of two or three lines”</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks Hashit! The only problem is that on my site the paragraph is on top of img a and img c. Not right after img c.

Comment: can i see live example.?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the fiddle with this working code: http://jsfiddle.net/gUuVn/5/

First, you'll need to add a "wrap" div with `position: relative` to contain the entire group. This allows us to absolutely position elements relative to that containing element, instead of the entire document.

More on this here: http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/

Then we'll wrap image C with a div. This allows us to absolutely position the image, while still allowing us to center it. If we were to absolutely position the image, we would no longer be able to center the image.

Once we absolutely position the wrap element, we then use `margin: 0 auto;` to center the image within that element.

**Additional markup around image C:**

```
<div class="c-wrap">
    <img src="http://s10.postimg.org/xt62u60dh/intro_bandera1.png"  class="c" />
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.wrap {
    position: relative;    
}
.c-wrap {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
}
.c {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Very nice! Let me see it! It still have some trouble with the Paragraph but maybe I can use your logic to solve it!

Answer (score 1):

This question has jQuery tagged in it, therefore I employed its use in my answer proposal:

I don't have time to finish this (the text) since I did this on a work break, but I got you started on something.  The fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YgbLX/

HTML:

```
 <div id ="a" class="background">
    <img id="b" src="http://s16.postimg.org/8ysqmfif9/tit_fondo2.jpg" style="position: absolute;"/>
    <img id="c" src="http://s10.postimg.org/xt62u60dh/intro_bandera1.png" style="position: absolute;"/>

     <p style="position: absolute; color:#755C48; font:italic 10px arial;position: relative;">Paragraph with a shor text of two or three lines”</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.background { 
    background-image: url(http://s22.postimg.org/o27ibahxd/tit_fondo1.jpg); 
    height: 301px;
    width: 480px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$("#b").css("top", ($("#a").height() - $("#b").height() + 10) + "px");
$("#c").css("left",  ($("#a").width()/2 - $("#c").width()/2) + "px");
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to give C also a position like `left: 100px` or `top: 100px` for example

Comment: I didn't say ity but the problem with this is that the images will change the size depending on the screen where are open.